# Why does WebView.InvokeScriptAsync throw exception 0x80020101 when calling an object added via AddWebAllowedObject?

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a UWP app in which I have defined the following class in a Windows Runtime Component project within my solution:

```
[AllowForWeb]
public sealed class WebViewCallback
{
    public string Cookie { get; set; }

    public void reportCookie(string cookie)
    {
        Cookie = cookie;
    }
}
```

From my main app assembly, I have a WebView (navigated to some URL) where I do the following:

```
private async void MyWebView_FrameDOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{    
    var callback = new WebViewCallback();
    MyWebView.AddWebAllowedObject("WebViewCallback", callback);

    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "WebViewCallback.reportCookie(document.cookie);" });
}
```

This throws 0x80020101 (SCRIPT_E_REPORTED), suggesting that the JS engine was not able to find (or not allowed to call) my callback object.

I suspect that somehow I'm not fulfilling the requirements for AddWebAllowedObject as documented in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_AddWebAllowedObject_System_String_System_Object_):

> The object passed into AddWebAllowedObject must be imported from a
>   Windows Runtime component that is separate from the app assembly. This
>   is necessary for the AllowForWeb attribute to be property identified
>   by the WebView security subsystem. If you use a class from your app
>   project, AddWebAllowedObject does not work.

Is there maybe something else I need to do with my Windows Runtime Component assembly? I simply added it to my solution like I would any C# assembly.

I'm using VS2017 and Win10 Creators Update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Apparently AddWebAllowedObject is very sensitive to when it is called. Everything works great if (and apparently only if) AddWebAllowedObject is called in the **NavigationStarting** event of the WebView. It will silently fail if it is called in some other event handler right before script that uses it is invoked (as I was doing in my repro code).